# react CSS transitions not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

Trying to fiddle out how to animate a part of component being rendered.

```
  renderContent() {
    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionAppear={true}
        transitionName={{
          enter: css.example__appear,
          appear: css.example__appear_active,
        }}
        transitionAppearTimeout={300}
        transitionEnterTimeout={300}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        >
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <Version />
        <Footer />
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`App ${css.host}`}>
        <Preloader />
        { this.props.isLoading ? null : this.renderContent() }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

When the `Preloader` finishes loading it sets the `isLoading` to `false` and `renderContent()` is being displayed but without any transitions. Is there any possibility to animate the contents of `renderContent`, when it is being fired?

Comment: Can you also provide all related css classes? It is not clear if you have a css class for the state appearActive

Answer (score 0):

From what I see is that your definition of transition names is not correct. 'enter' just handles the enter transitions, the case where a new element is added to the list of items. This needs a .enter and a .enter-active class.

'appear' handles the case for onMount transition and would also need to have two classes: .appear and .appear-active. You somehow seem to have mixed it up. Cause you set:

```
 enter: css.example__appear,
 appear: css.example__appear_active
```

What would be correct:

```
enter: css.example_enter
enterActive: css.example_enter_active
appear: css.example_appear
appearActive: css.example_appear_active
```

See more in the document attached: https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html#custom-classes